# Active admin allowing admin to change views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have the contact details in the front page. Is it possible to allow the admin to change these details dynamically from the back-end?

contact.html.erb

```
<h3>Contact</h3>
<p>Email: example@example.co.uk</p>
<p>Twitter: @example</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to store the contact details in a table in the database, and set up a model for this. You can't set up ActiveAdmin to edit plain text in one of your view templates.

Once you have your model you can easily use ActiveAdmin for editing the single row that you need for these details.

```
rails g model ContactDetail email:string twitter:string
```

Then create a single row with your defaults:

```
> rails console
ContactDetail.create(email: "example@example.co.uk", twitter: "@example")
```

Then put this in the controller for your contact page:

```
@contact_detail = ContactDetail.first
```

And tweak the view:

```
<h3>Contact</h3>
<p>Email: <%= @contact_detail.email %></p>
<p>Twitter: <%= @contact_detail.twitter %></p>
```

Now in your **app/admin/contact_details.rb** you just need:

```
ActiveAdmin.register ContactDetail do
  index do
    column :email
    column :twitter
  end
end
```